# Unity game health below zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have 100 health and different enemies who deal different amounts of damage. The problem is that sometimes my health goes negative which I don't want to have. Probably the problem is that I have an enemy who deals like 50 damage and my current health is 60 so it goes negative. That is the way I tried to fix it (it doesn't do the job):

```
health -= damage;
    currentHealth.text = health.ToString();

    if(health < 0)
    {
        health = 0;
    }
    if (health == 0)
    {
        Die();
    }
```

Die is basically setting the gameobject inactive. Any ideas?

I would be very grateful

Kind regards

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't do the job"? You don't explain what problem this code has

Comment: if your damage is 50 but your health was 60 and it goes negative -  something else is wrong

Comment: How about doing the `currentHealth.text = health.ToString();` **after** clamping the value? And why not simply `if(health <= 0){ Die(); }` ?

Comment: @UnholySheep well I mean by that that my idea didn't work :D
A negative number is displayed on my UI

Comment: @derHugo even if that seemed weird for me, it worked :D thanks!

Comment: If you call `toString` before clamping `health` to 0 then obviously it will give you a negative number in the UI. I'm not sure what seems weird about that to you

Answer (score 1):

So as said you want to print your value **after** clamping it to `0`.

You could do this in a single line using e.g.

```
health = Mathf.Max(0, health - damage);
currentHealth.text = health.ToString();

if(health <= 0)
{
    Die();
}
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest the exact same thing. Health should be normalised like @derHugo does in his first line of code.